# How To Number x Amout of Strings, Based Off the Amount of Items in an Array

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to get strings that are numbered based on how many items are in a previous array.
I didn't bother showing how the array is made, but depending on the case the array could have anywhere from 1-∞ items in it.

```
array = ["soup:9273", "soup:2945", "soup:3826"] #make soup array
print(array)

count = len(array)   #count how many soups there are
print(count) #out put 3

print() #print out "soup1" + "soup2" + "soup3"
```

Any ideas/help is greatly appreciated, Thank You

Comment: No the array always contains soup, however if theres 4 soup items in the array. I need to create a string called Soup1, and another called Soup2, all the way to Soup4. (or however many items are in the array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
array = ["soup:9273", "soup:2945", "soup:3826"]

count_arr = [x.split(":")[0] + str(i) for i, x in enumerate(array, start=1)]

print(*count_arr)

Output: soup1 soup2 soup3
```

**Explanation**

Create an index from 1.. for each array entry

```
enumerate(array, start=1)
```

Iteratate to get index and item for each element in array

```
x.split(":")[0] + str(i) for i in enumerate(array, start=1)
```